# <span> inside a Bootstrap well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

Here is my problem: I would like to use `<span>` to color a date inside a bootstrap `.well`. Here is a part of my code:

```css
  .cv span.date{
 font-weight:bold !important;
 color: #5882FA !important;
  }
```

```html
<div id="cv" class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="well"><span class="date">2016-2018</span> I ate sandwiches </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the problem: No matter what I do, the `<span>`'s content inherit the `.well`'s properties. I've already tried to give an "id" to the span instead of a "class", and to put the color and bold properties inside the `<span>` balise.
How can I put my date in bold and color?

Answer (score 1):

Your container `<div>` is using an id `#cv` not a class `.cv`. You can also be [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on your CSS rule of the `<span>`:

```css
#cv div.well span.date {
  color: #5882FA;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="cv" class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="well"><span class="date">2016-2018</span> I ate sandwiches </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! don't forget to [mark as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS selector, you are calling .cv - which is incorrect, since cv is an ID:

```
 #cv span.date{
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #5882FA;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That can only happen if `.well`

1.) has a CSS rule with higher specifity and also uses `!important`, or

2.) if the rule for `.well` follows *after*  your rule for `.cv span.date`, has at least the same specifity and also uses `!important`

So try to give your rule a specifity as high as possible. From your piece of code, the selector with the highest possible specifity would be

```
div#cv.container.text-center > div.row > div.col-sm-4 > div.well > span.date {
  font-weight:bold !important;
  color: #5882FA !important;
}
```